# How to send phone number to viber?

Tags: android, android-intent, viber

I am using this code to send message with viber:

```
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text to share");
        share.setPackage("com.viber.voip");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
```

But I want to send number with message to viber.
I check this code to send number, but not working:

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, "0000000");
```

Comment: are you found any solution?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to send a message to groups of Viber using computer?